# Shell: How to extract data from an ever running program

Tags: shell, sh, network-scan, network-security, aircrack-ng

I am writing a shell script and I have a command "airodump-ng" and this program runs forever capturing the information about the access points. What I want to do in my script is to run the program and capture some information after exactly 10 seconds. So to put it in general terms, how can I capture some information from a live running program in my script. The format of "airodump-ng" is given below.

[image]

Comment: Have your daemon append its updates to a log file that your script reads.

Comment: @Lorehead How do I do that? I am using >> operator but when I go to the file it is empty

Answer (score 1):

aircrack-ng has its own command to store stream data into a file like csv and other formats

```
airodump-ng --write /sd/airodump.pcap --output-format pcap mon0
```